# laravel 4 hasOne/ hasMany / belongsTo doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have some models belong to Activity Model.

in my Activity.php I had

```
<?php

class Activity extends \Eloquent {
     protected $fillable = [];

     public function activity_car_nums()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('ActivityCarNum');
     }

     public function newables()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('Newable');
     }

     public function serial_codes() 
     {
         return $this->hasMany('SerialCode');
     }

     public function applys()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('Apply');
     }

}
```

and in SerialCode.php, I had

```
<?php

class SerialCode extends \Eloquent {
     protected $fillable = ['code'];

     public function activity()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('Activity');
     }
}
```

and in my controller, when I wrote

```
$serial_codes = [];
while(count($serial_codes) < $serial_code_total)
{
    $code = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),0,5);
    $serial_code = new SerialCode(['code' => $code]);

    if(!in_array($serial_code, $serial_codes))
    {
        $serial_codes[] = $serial_code;
    }
}

$activity->serial_codes()->saveMany($serial_codes);
```

it works.

But when it turns to

```
//this can get activity object
$activity = Activity::find($id);

//this can get the serial codes of the object above.
$serial_codes = SerialCode::whereActivityId($id)->get();

//this don't work, it returns null
$serial_codes = $activity->serial_codes;
```

for I really don't know why...

Can anybody help me please, and sorry for my poor English. Thank You.
(If you need any code else please tell me.)

Comment: I have other 2 Models that associate as hasOne and belongs to relationship, and I can't get anything via orm query even if there is data inside as well.

Comment: Can you post SerialCode and Activity models?

Comment: @Laerte I updated on my question :)

Comment: What is the key you are using to link Activity and SerialCode?

Comment: I have activity_id in SerialCode Model
like this
`$table->integer('activity_id')->unsigned();
   $table->foreign('activity_id')->references('id')->on('activities');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason that why my model query cannot work, because the "_" in function name.

just change

```
public function serial_codes()
```

to

```
public function serialcodes()
```

then everything will go fine.

Thank to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

my model code:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
class Product extends Model
{
    public $table="s_products";
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
    public function reviews()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\ProductReview');
        }
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AttributeMapping');
    }        
    public function images()
       {
           return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
       }  
}
```

Comment: should I change all model by adding `namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
class MyModel extends Model` ???

Comment: After I changed all model like that, I got **Class 'Activity' not found** with `$activities = Activity::latest()->get();`

Comment: @hubuki im using transfromer

Comment: in that transfromer i use images()